# Can I push information back to phonegap without request?

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, io

I am trying to develop an app that has a broadcast receiver. When I get a phone call, I want to be able to pass the number back to my phonegap app. I am a web developer and I know that the nature of web is pulling, not pushing (lack of I/O), but since it is still in a Java app is there a way I can pass those values back to my phonegap app and append it to a list?

```
  if (messages.length > -1) {
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getOriginatingAddress(), duration);
                        toast.show();
```

Comment: Basically, once you have the data in your activity you can just call javascript functions from the html page. The `CordoveWebView` have a function called `sendJavaScript`, that sends javascript to the page. I'm not a web developer myself, but I used it from the Java side. Anyway, your question wasn't so clear so I wasn't sure what you are asking. If it's not what you asked please expand your question.

Comment: uhm sort of. i put in a snippet of my code. this works and all(toasts) even with phonegap app. but instead of toast i want to putsh it back to the webview. But like i said the nature of html/js is pull not push .... i know how to pass info back to the main activity(sort of) but.. it doesnt help me because I want it back on my html page without performing an action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To push data to the `WebView` you need to use the `sendJavaScript` function of `CordoveWebView` (the PhoneGap's implemented `WebView`), or use the `loadUrl` function of `WebView`.

To use the `CordovaWebView` way:

```
mCordovaWebView.sendJavaScript("pushDataFunc('data')");
```

To use the `WebView` way:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:pushDataFunc('data')");
```

And if you are extending `DroidGap` you can call the function on the activity itself:

```
YourDroidGapActivity.this.sendJavaScript("pushDataFunc('data')");
```

Comment: the mCordovaWebView do i have to import anything else? also, the mWebview has the same issue, it wants me to import the webkit client

Comment: @Dnaso, sorry I didn't understand you. Can you explain what you are asking again? Please remember that I don't have knowledge in web, I have knowledge in the Java side.

Comment: where I have toast.show().. instead of providing a toast I want to bring the info back to the phonegap portion of my app.

Comment: How do you use the PhoneGap in your application? Extending `DroidGap` instead of `Activity`? Or adding a `CordovaWebView` to your UI?

Comment: extending droid gap. Its the main component not just a child of a bigger app due to the fact the app isnt all that big and I can still register services using it.

Comment: So just use `this.sendJavascript()` in your `DroidGap` activity. It passes it to the `CordovaWebView` that inside your activity.

Comment: all i have to do is pass the function name?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26974/discussion-between-elad92-and-dnaso)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) where in Web pushes message to the phone.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with Phonegap, I am a native app developer. I couldn't even understand the exact functionality you were talking about.

Comment: would you like to throw more salt in my wounds?